Tensorflow in pip list but fail to import
I built, with much effort, tensorflow 2.10.1 from source.
$ pip list -v | grep tensorflow
tensorflow                   2.10.1              /home/abarrachina/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
tensorflow-estimator         2.10.0              /home/abarrachina/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem 0.36.0              /home/abarrachina/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip

However, when trying to import
$ python
Python 3.9.2 (default, Feb 28 2021, 17:03:44) 
[GCC 10.2.1 20210110] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sysconfig; print(sysconfig.get_paths()["purelib"])
/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages
>>> import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'

I see as if I have two paths for python, /usr/lib/python3.9 and /home/abarrachina/.local/lib/python3.9. But I failed to change it, I try alias python=/home/abarrachina/.local/lib/python3.9 and still the previous commands do not change. Also, for all other packages seems to work, for example, numpy is also in /home/abarrachina/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip and it works (same versiona and everything).
What can be happening?

Update Python 3.12.5.

If you just did alias on the terminal then it will only be valid till the current shell is opened so maybe that's why your issue persists.
If you want to use your own python stored at .local just add this alias command in ~/.bashrc if you use bash.
alias python="/home/abarrachina/.local/lib/python3.9"

Do  source ~/.bashrc if you want it to work in the current shell otherwise whenever you will open a new shell your python will be aliased to the one stored at .local.
Double check using
python -V

To make sure the python version and
python 
>>> import sysconfig; print(sysconfig.get_paths()["purelib"])

This should give the output to your python stored at .local
Also if you do
which python

it will still show you the original path not the aliased path.
You can also remove the python stored at /usr/lib but I won't recommend it as many programs might have dependencies on that.
However I recommend you to use miniconda or venv as you can create a different isolated environments for different projects based on your needs.
